# Unnamed class/typename in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, typename

I was looking through the documentation of [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and there was this template declaration:

```
template<typename SomeType>
struct inner_type { typedef typename SomeType::type type; };
template <
    class T,
    class = typename T::type,            // SFINAE failure if T has no member type
    class U = typename inner_type<T>::type // hard error if T has no member type
                                          // (guaranteed to not occur as of C++14)
> void foo(int) {}
```

Specifically, I'm asking about `class = typename T::type`. What's the point of declaring an unnamed class?

Because of the comment I thought that this will result in a compiler error when `T` doesn't have a member `type`, but that isn't the case, as `foo<int, int, int>(0);` compiles fine.

On the other hand

```
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>>
void foo(T t) {}
```

doesn't compile if `T` is signed, and compiles if `T` is unsigned.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like you are only supposed to call `foo` as `foo<int>(0)` instead of overriding the template parameters that remove the template from overload substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `foo<int, int, int>(0);` compiles fine.

Because you specify the 2nd template argument, then the default template argument (i.e. `typename T::type`) won't be used, then won't trigger compile error.

If you just write `foo<int>(0);` to make the default template argument to be used, compile will fail.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/LHBV83897)

And it's same for your 2nd sample too.

> What's the point of declaring an unnamed class?

Because the template parameter won't be used for the template implementation.